# Ninject factory extensions with async await

Tags: c#, async-await, ninject

If I use a a factory interface such as this

```
public interface IBoredFactory
{
    IBored Create(<some args>)
}
```

and in the binding do this

```
kernel.Bind<IBoredFactory>().ToFactory();
kernel.Bind<IBored>().To<Yawn>();
```

it works just as expected, and the code returns a Yawn

But if I change the Factory interface to this

```
public interface IBoredFactory
{
    Task<IBored> Create(<some args>)
}
```

The factory proxy gets built, but the thread never returns from the `Create()`, the caller endlessly awaits.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I'm guessing the FactoryProvider instantiates and returns a Task<IBored>. Since Task<IBorded> most probably does not have IBored as a dependency in the constructor, Ninject will not inject anything into the Task.

Answer (score -1):

As @Andreas Appelros suggests Ninject is returning an unfinished `Task<T>`.

As there's actually no async ninject API it does not really make sense to use async-await for resolving instances, even if there'd be something async involved in the creation, this would first need to be converted to a synchronous-call to satisfy ninject's binding API's (["sync over async"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)) - which is not really a good thing to do. Then do convert it it to async again (["async over sync"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)) doesn't make any more sense, either, as it's just adding overhead.

However, if for some reason you still want to do it, you'll have to use a custom `IInstanceProvider`, for example the following will work (code can be improved, though):

```
public class AsyncInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    public override object GetInstance(
        IInstanceResolver instanceResolver, MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        object result = base.GetInstance(
            instanceResolver, methodInfo, arguments);
        if (ReturnsTaskResult(methodInfo))
        {
            return CreateFinishedTask(methodInfo, result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected override Type GetType(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (ReturnsTaskResult(methodInfo))
        {
            return methodInfo.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        }

        return base.GetType(methodInfo, arguments);
    }

    private bool ReturnsTaskResult(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return (methodInfo.ReturnType.IsGenericType 
                && methodInfo.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>));
    }

    private object CreateFinishedTask(MethodInfo methodInfo, object result)
    {
        var openGenericMethod = typeof(Task).GetMethod("FromResult");
        var closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(
            methodInfo.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        return closedGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[1] { result });
    }
}
```

### Globally Applying the new `IInstanceProvider`

If you want to use that Instance Provider globally, perform the following rebind after loading the Factory extension:

```
Rebind<IInstanceProvider>().To<AsyncInstanceProvider>();
```

### Complete Test-Code

And, for reference, the complete code including a sync and an async test (requires xunit and FluentAssertion nuget packages):

```
namespace NinjectTest.AsyncFactory_44983826
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;
    using Ninject.Extensions.Factory.Factory;

    using FluentAssertions;

    using Xunit;

    public class AsyncInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
    {
        public override object GetInstance(IInstanceResolver instanceResolver, MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
        {
            object result = base.GetInstance(instanceResolver, methodInfo, arguments);
            if (ReturnsTaskResult(methodInfo))
            {
                return CreateFinishedTask(methodInfo, result);
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected override Type GetType(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
        {
            if (ReturnsTaskResult(methodInfo))
            {
                return methodInfo.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            }

            return base.GetType(methodInfo, arguments);
        }

        private bool ReturnsTaskResult(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return (methodInfo.ReturnType.IsGenericType && methodInfo.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>));
        }

        private object CreateFinishedTask(MethodInfo methodInfo, object result)
        {
            var openGenericMethod = typeof(Task).GetMethod("FromResult");
            var closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(methodInfo.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
            return closedGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[1] { result });
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }

        public Bar Bar { get; private set; }

        public Foo(string id, Bar bar)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Bar = bar;
        }
    }

    public class Bar { }

    public interface IFactory
    {
        Foo Create(string id);

        Task<Foo> CreateAsync(string id);
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SyncTest()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel
                .Bind<IFactory>()
                .ToFactory(() => new AsyncInstanceProvider());

            const string expectedId = "Hello You!";

            kernel.Get<IFactory>().Create(expectedId)
                .Id.Should().Be(expectedId);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task AsyncTest()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel
                .Bind<IFactory>()
                .ToFactory(() => new AsyncInstanceProvider());

            const string expectedId = "Hello You!";

            Foo result = await kernel.Get<IFactory>().CreateAsync(expectedId);

            result.Id.Should().Be(expectedId);
        }
    }
}
```